# Can we index only one field of json log file in splunk

Tags: splunk

When running an application in EKS, the container logs are coming in the format of:

`{ log: 2021-08-04 12:28:24,803INFO hostname com.application.RequestListener Sent response with request_id=1  stream: stdout time: 2021-08-04T12:28:24.803533339Z }`

As I am only interested in the value relating to log, if there a way I can extract only:

`2021-08-04 12:28:24,803INFO hostname com.application.RequestListener Sent response with request_id=1`

I have tried setting source to log in outputs.conf, however, this does not seem to work and I still get the json format present in the splunk search head

Comment: How are you onboarding that log?  What are the props.conf settings for that sourcetype?  Have you looked at `SEDCMD`?  Have you considered Cribl?  BTW, outputs.conf says where the data goes, but has no effect on the data itself.

Comment: Seems like those are docker logs. You can find better solutions to forward logs to Splunk. Including Splunk Connect for Kubernetes and Collectord from outcoldsolutions